# sort file to have same column order as another file

Tags: r

I have two files `s` and `df.iso` that share the same column-names. I would like to sort the `s` file so that the columns are in the same order as the `df.iso` file. Part of the two files shown below (there are much more columns than shown)

```
> head(s)
         100G    100R   106G    106R    122G    122R   124G    124R    126G   126R
Cal01   64982   40617  16687   34169   60261   62723  20196   55175   46234  11648
Cal02   23241   19762   8237   27298   22358   24350  14503   23792   20989   6514
Cal03  377255  317826 101387  254313  330619  394603 168218  311727  275783  99379
Cal04   35172   30102  10305   39377   33148   34551  15897   34986   24039   7224
Cal05     208     271    104     150     287     185    154     347     180     33
Cal06 1588672 1386207 443956 1119972 1533890 1784794 571805 1368031 1257916 451750

> head(df.iso)
                                     185R 68G 60G 134G 124R 279R 126G 26R 73G 192G 100R
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCCT     1   6   1    2    2    1    2   2   1    1    1
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTT      1   0   1    1    4    0    0   1   1    0    2
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTC     4   5   2   12    4    1    2   3   4    2    4
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCC    7   5   2    6    3    2    2   2   1    1    2
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT   15   6  14   49   32    7   20  20   8   13   22
hsa-let-7a-3p_CCATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT    4   1   1    0    0    1    1   0   3    2    1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both data.frames (not files) have the same columns, you can

```
xy1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = runif(3), c = rnorm(3))
xy2 <- data.frame(c = rnorm(3), a = 1:3, b = runif(3))

xy2

           c a         b
1 -0.7573781 1 0.9564583
2  0.3513074 2 0.9837766
3  1.6455091 3 0.9433857

xy2[, names(xy1)]

  a         b          c
1 1 0.9564583 -0.7573781
2 2 0.9837766  0.3513074
3 3 0.9433857  1.6455091
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're starting with the data frames already read into R from the files. If their column names are exactly the same, one easy way to do this is to reorder both by column names:

```
s = s[ , order(colnames(s))]
df.iso = df.iso[ , order(colnames(df.iso))]
```

You can then write these to the files. Ordering the column names make the data frames more easily comparable and also has the added benefit of making it easier to find any given column name in either data frame or file.